# Resources for teaching calc III

Tags: multivariable-calculus, education

So I was very unsatisfied with how I taught Calc III a couple years ago, and this summer I have to do it again.  Are there any general resources for teaching this course?  It seems like there should be, since it's a very standard thing.

In particular I'm interested in tools to show students visual graphics so they can really see what's happening in spaces we work in.

But I'm also interested in general insight on how to reach students at this level.  Any tips or tricks are welcome.  Anything you can point me to.

Thanks.

Comment: I think [math educators.SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) is a better site for asking this sort of questions.

Comment: @achillehui oh rock on I didn't know that existed!